# Complexity of List.mem

Tags: algorithm, list, ocaml, complexity-theory

I have an algorithm manipulating a list, and I would like to express its complexity.

In the algorithm, I have `List.mem a l` inside a loop, and I am not sure how to consider the complexity of `List.mem`, must it be `O(List.length(l))`, or `Ocaml` can do something magic inside to be better than `O(List.length(l))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no magic, here's the implementation (OCaml 3.12.0):

```
let rec mem x = function
    [] -> false
  | a::l -> compare a x = 0 || mem x l
```

If you have an OCaml source distribution, this is in the file named `stdlib/list.ml` (line 135).

Comment: By the way, where can you see this piece of code in a OCaml distribution?

Answer (score 1):

No, with a linked list, the best you can theoretically do to check for membership is O(n). You can improve on that by sacrificing space, i.e. using a hashtable instead, or having a hashtable alongside this list if you care about order.